# Chrome Devtools, copying over a set of answers

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have to do this repeatedly, so I was wondering if there was a working around....

here is a set of amenities for an apartment, they have to be transferred to a larger list containing those amenities by clicking off multiple choice cirlces. Is there away to edit the script to do it all at once>

example
accessible
air conditioning
dishwasher
garage
hardwood floors
parking
patio / balcony
gym
in unit laundry
cats allowed
dogs allowed
pet friendly
basketball court
bathtub
bbq/grill
bike storage
business center
carpet
ceiling fan
clubhouse
game room
granite counters
microwave
oven
package receiving
playground
pool table
range
refrigerator
stainless steel
walk in closets

Comment: You might need to add the html structure to get a quicker response. You can do this by getting the html from the elements tab with a right click.

Comment: <div class="form-field whitelist-searchable-amenity">
<input name="property[amenity_whitelist][]" type="hidden" value=""><input type="checkbox" value="accessible" name="property[amenity_whitelist][]" id="property_amenity_whitelist_accessible">
<label for="property_accessible">Accessible</label>
</div>

Comment: the word Accessible is the word being copied

Comment: im just trying to pull the first list, into the application, to check off all the options, without  having to do it manually each time

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to just checkmark all of the checkboxes on the amenities list so something like this will work:

```
$('div.whitelist-searchable-amenity input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r62qgou3/

Edit:
I am not sure of what you mean by "copying text to script" but I modified the script to check if the values that you are looking for are within the document. This should search the values of the checkboxes and then you can use your own script to "copy" the value elsewhere. Just add more values to the array if you need more keywords.

```
x = [
    "accessible",
    "air conditioning",
    "dishwasher",
    "garage", 
];

$('div.whitelist-searchable-amenity input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    if(x.indexOf(this.value) > -1)
    {
      alert("copy here");
    }
});
```

Comment: i only posted one line of code because it wouldnt let me fit it all

Comment: but there is that same code for all the amenities listed above, in a column,

Comment: I go through hotel sites and copy the amenities into a program that pulls key words to match  what i had listed above, of course most hotels dont have all those amenities..., so it there a way to copy the text over to the code so it checks off only the amenties in that list?